# Authentification with JWT tokens between NestJS API and Websocket app

Tags: websocket, axios, jwt, nestjs

I have a little bit of trouble figuring out how to authentify my websocket to my NestJS app using the JWT tokens.

Here is the hierarchy of my apps :

- Front: Angular/Ionic, when a user authentify in the connection portal, my NestJS backend returns him a JWT token containing the session (email, name, roles and groups of the user blabla...). We don't want the WS to have an entry in the database and to use this auth function.
- Backend : NestJS/Sequelize, Every API points are guarded on authentification and authorization, meaning that you can't call an API point without a JWT Token (except the auth API for the user). Also, if you don't have the permission (or the role) to access the API, then the authorization guard will block your call.
- Websocket : JS/Axios, in this project we need a websocket to contact our machines, and this websocket needs to update the database using the NestJS API points called by Axios. But it can't, because of the Authentification guard and Authorization guard.

So my question is : how can I call a NestJS API point from my WS with those guards? :)

I tried to create a static custom JWT token for the WS only and put it in the .env of the WS, but some API points needs information inside the token that the WS can't have (like email, user_id, client_id...). So it's not very optimized...

I also tried to put some kind of conditions in my guards for the WS but it was not safe at all...

I thought about other things like duplicate my API points for the WS only in local on the server, not so safe either...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had that kind of architecture issues. One thing that has worked for me is to create a service account. In this specific case, I would create an account just for the WS Service with all the required fields (email, user_id, etc.), and generate a JWT token only for that service account. That way, your guards would allow the request to pass through.

Comment: Hello ! I think it's the best solution, i can't see anything else for now so i'll do that :) Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

When is this api endpoint called ?
For instance, let's say it's upon your websocket's connection event, or whatever trigger of your choosing, create a POST call to you API endpoint (which should be authentified with your JWT token)

something like

```js
const myWS = new WebSocket(...)
ws.onopen = (event) => {
  //could be onmessage or whenever
  const data = JSON.parse(event.data)
  fetch(my_protected_endpoint, { 
    method: "POST", 
    body: JSON.stringify({ ...mydata })
    headers: { ...myheaders }
  })
}
```

Unless I missunderstood your problem - which is possible